# JavaScript redirect with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, redirect, href

So I have this JavaScript function getSearchVariable which basically acquires a variable from the URL using raw Javascript.

I need to redirect the user to a page with a URL with some static text before the variable and after the variable.

```
document.location.href="http://example.com/tracer?="+(getSearchVariable('Track')+"&tba=N"
```

Any idea on why something like the code above won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are missing a )

```
document.location.href="http://example.com/tracer?="+(getSearchVariable('Track')+"&tba=N"
                                                     ^1                ^2      ^2
```

it should be

```
document.location.href="http://example.com/tracer?="+(getSearchVariable('Track'))+"&tba=N"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your parenthesis are not balanced.

```
document.location.href=
    "http://example.com/tracer?="+(getSearchVariable('Track')+"&tba=N"
//                                ^
//                                |
//                                +--- Remove this guy.
```